# Swift function stops running?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following function that attempts to log a user into my app using Firebase:

```
func tryLogin(email: String, password: String) -> Bool {
    var loginSuccess = false

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (dataResult, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            loginSuccess = false
        } else {
            print("logged in \(email)")
            loginSuccess = true
        }
        print("end of closure")
    }

    print("Returning -- \(loginSuccess)\n\n\n")
    return loginSuccess
}
```

However, when called, it seems to run up until it prints "end of closure", end if a correct email and password is provided prints "logged in", but no further. "Returning..." never gets printed. Any reason why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's asynchronous

```
func tryLogin(email: String, password: String,completion:@escaping(_ res:Bool) -> Void ) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (dataResult, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            completion(false)
        } else {
            print("logged in \(email)")
            completion(true)
        }
        print("end of closure")
    }

}
```

//

Call

```
tryLogin(email:<#email#>,password:<#password#>) {  (res) in
  print(res)
}
```

Comment: Ha! Just as I was about to say it's because it's happening asynchronous!

Comment: just saw your edit to call -  thanks!